# GOOGLE FCM (Cloud Messaging) Notifications Not Showing up on Mobile Device

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a mobile application with Push Notification. The App grabs the Token from Google FCM stores it into a database. Then we use a dashboard to send a notification to all registered devices.

There has been an issue with our notifications. Although it shows successful on FCM Response, the message does not go to devices.

FCM Response:  `{"multicast_id":8418406699445470273,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1531307530435857%b446114df9fd7ecd"}]}`

PHP Code:

```
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    // Set GCM post variables (device IDs and push payload)     
    $post = array(
                    'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                    'data'              => $data, 
                    'priority'              => 'high',    
                    'notification' => $data,               
                    );

    // Set CURL request headers (authentication and type)       
    $headers = array( 
                        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );

    // Initialize curl handle       
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set URL to GCM endpoint      
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    // Set request method to POST       
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    // Set our custom headers       
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    // Get the response back as string instead of printing it       
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    // Set JSON post data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

    // Actually send the push   
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    // Error handling
    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
    {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    }

    // Close curl handle
    curl_close( $ch );

    // Debug GCM response       
    echo $result;
```

I have sent the same message through Google Cloud Message Console and it did send the notification to my device.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: on which of the platform iOS or Android?

Comment: Could you describe the contents of $data

Comment: Priyam: Its for Android

Comment: Arthur: $data = array( 'message' =>$nsubject, 'sound' => 'default', 'body' =>$nsurl,'icon'=>"http://www.bozcadercharity.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo-bozca-2.png");

Answer (score 0):

**This Code is perfect working i have notification get, i have already use this code**

```
 <?php
    $t = $_POST["tokan"];
    $msg = $_POST["msg"];
    function sendMessage($data, $t)
    {
        //FCM api URL
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        if (!defined('KEY_VALUE'))
            define('KEY_VALUE', 'webapikey');

        $fields         = array();
        $fields['data'] = $data;
        $fields['to']   = $t;

        //header with content_type api key
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key=' . KEY_VALUE
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
    $data = array(

        'post_msg' => $msg,
        'post_title' => "help",
    );

    sendMessage($data, $t);
    echo "success";

    ?>
```

Comment: Result with your code:  {"multicast_id":4641890741778347559,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1531310267485098%b446114df9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: I do get this result with my code too. However, I do not get it to my device. I enter same token ID to google console and it does send the notification to my device.

Comment: You have add manifest file permission  
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
        <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
        <service android:name=".RegistrationIntentService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" /> </intent-filter></service>

Comment: Amar: This code is already added to the Android app. The device receives the notification that is sent via Google Firebase Cloud Messaging Console.